# Como juntar esses dois arrays

Tags: php

Tenho dois array que são gerados pelos inputs:

**Pergunta**

```
<input type="hidden" name="pergunta[]" value="<?= $row_rs['pergunta']; ?>">
```

e **Opções**

```
<input type="hidden" name="opcao[<?= $i; ?>][]" value="<?= strip_tags($rowOpcoes['opcao']); ?>">
```

Como faço para juntar o `array` **[pergunta]** e **[opcao]** em uma só variável, `$prova`, para salvar no banco de dados?

### INSERT

```
if ((isset($_POST["form"])) && ($_POST['form'] == "form1")) {

  $prova = array($_POST['pergunta'], $_POST['opcao']);

  $rs = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO provas (codigo, titulo, prova, id_disciplina, data) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");

  $rs->bind_param('sssss',
    $_POST['codigo'],
    $_POST['titulo'],
    $prova,
    $_POST['id_disciplina'],
    $_POST['data']
    );

  $rs->execute();
  $ultimoId = $rs->insert_id;


  if ($rs->errno) {
    echo 'Erro: ', $rs->error;
  } else {
    echo "<script>window.location='sucesso.php'</script>";
  }

}
```

### print_r($_POST)

```
Array
(
    [id_disciplina] => 5
    [titulo] => Teste
    [pergunta] => Array
        (
            [0] => Questão 2 de teste:

            [1] => Questão 4 de teste:

            [2] => Questão 1 de teste:

            [3] => Questão 3 de teste:

            [4] => TESTE 50?


        )

    [opcao] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a) resposta 1 - Q2
                    [1] => b) resposta 2 - Q2
                    [2] => c) resposta 3 - Q2
                    [3] => d) resposta 4 - Q2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a) Muito obrigado!
                    [1] => b) Socorro!
                    [2] => c) “Grande nau, grande tormenta”.
                    [3] => d) “A distância alimenta o sonho”.
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a) resposta 1 - Q1
                    [1] => b) resposta 2 - Q1
                    [2] => c) resposta 3 - Q1
                    [3] => d) resposta 4 - Q1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a) resposta 1 - Q3
                    [1] => b) resposta 2 - Q3
                    [2] => c) resposta 3 - Q3
                    [3] => d) resposta 4 - Q3
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a) f
                    [1] => b) r
                    [2] => c) r
                )

        )

    [button] => 
    [form] => form1
    [cod] => P5508182
    [data] => 2019-08-28
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para salvar os dados no banco da pergunta e as atividades da forma que pretente, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
$pergunta = $_POST['pergunta']:
$opcoes = $_POST['opcao']:



$prova = json_encode([$pergunta, $opcoes]);
```

Para extrair os dados, você pode inverter o resultado da sua consulta:

```
$prova = json_decode($rs['prova']);
```

**Obs:** Um dos problemas de fazer desta forma é que futuramente você sempre terá que extrair os dados toda vez que for editar...

Mas em json ao menos você tem uma linha de dados acessível via javascript.